# How to handle 2D array with using Context in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This is where I created Context

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const GridContext = createContext([]);

export default GridContext;
```

this is How I am sending data using context.

```
const App = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const newGrid = getInitialGrid();
    setGrid(newGrid);
  }, []);
.....
if (grid.length === 0) {
    return (
      <GridContext.Provider value={grid}>
        <div className="App">
          <nav className="navbar">
            <div>
              <h1>Pathfinder Visualizer</h1>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Info />
          <Arena />
        </div>
      </GridContext.Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <GridContext.Provider value={grid}>
        <div className="App">
          <nav className="navbar">
            <div>
              <h1>Pathfinder Visualizer</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="navitem">
              <button className="btn" onClick={() => dijkstra()}>
                <span>Visualize</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Info />
          <Arena />
        </div>
      </GridContext.Provider>
```

This is where I need the 2d array.

```
const Arena = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useContext(GridContext);
  const [mouseIsPressed, setmouseIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [start, setStart] = useState([5, 5]);
....
console.log(GridContext._currentValue);
  //setGrid(GridContext._currentValue);
  console.log(grid);
  return <div></div>;
```

The output of first logger is 2d array while the output of second array is only the first row of 2d array. Also the setGrid is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the grid with useEffect post the initial render so its expected that initially the grid from context will give your only the empty row.

Also you are just passing `grid` to the context and not `setGrid` which is why its undefined and also if you destrutcutre in child you are actually destructuing the first and second row of grid.

Pass context value like an array and it will work

Also you can improve on your code by adding conditional render where you actually need it

```
const App = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const newGrid = getInitialGrid();
    setGrid(newGrid);
  }, []);
.....
  return (
      <GridContext.Provider value={[grid, setGrid]}>
        <div className="App">
          <nav className="navbar">
            <div>
              <h1>Pathfinder Visualizer</h1>
            </div>
             {grid.length > 0 && <div className="navitem">
              <button className="btn" onClick={() => dijkstra()}>
                <span>Visualize</span>
              </button>
            </div>}
          </nav>
          <Info />
          <Arena />
        </div>
      </GridContext.Provider>
    );
 }
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I didn't knew about passing setter also. Can you share me a good resource to learn about context.

Comment: react docs are great. Please refer https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Thank you very much